# Mapping Fasta to Fasta + Bed file to make new bed file

Tags: alignment, fasta

I've been thinking a lot about this problem and I don't know how to solve it (also asked here https://www.biostars.org/p/426234/ but not answer). 
I have a fasta file with microRNAs precursors and a bed file with the coordinates of this precursors in a genome.

fasta file microRNAs precursors:

```
>LQNS02278089.1_34108
CGGTCGTGATGGGAGCAAATTTGAACAATTAAATAGCAAATTGCACTCGTCCCGGCCTGC
>LQNS02278089.1_34106
CGGTCGTGATTGGTGCAACTTGGGTCACTTAACCGCCAATTGCACTGATCCCGGCCTGC
>LQNS02278089.1_34110
CGGCCGGTATGAGGGCAAATCAATTTCTGTATAAATGACGAATTGCACTCGTCCCGGCCTTC
```

bed file precursors:

```
LQNS02278089.1  848170  848230  LQNS02278089.1_34108    2249659.3   -   848170  848230  0,0,255
LQNS02278089.1  847652  847711  LQNS02278089.1_34106    1566285.5   -   847652  847711  0,0,255
LQNS02278089.1  848490  848552  LQNS02278089.1_34110    882643.1    -   848490  848552  0,0,255
```

I also have a fasta file of mature microRNAs sequences that I would like to map to the precursors fasta file to obtain another bed file for the matures microRNAs.

fasta file mature microRNAs:

```
>LQNS02278089.1_34108
AATTGCACTCGTCCCGGCCTGC
>LQNS02278089.1_34106
AATTGCACTGATCCCGGCCTGC
>LQNS02278089.1_34110
AATTGCACTCGTCCCGGCCTTC
```

Any help or recommendation will be very appreciated!

Comment: Index the fasta with the precursors, align the mature sequences against the indexed precursors and process the sam output along with the bed file with some hand-made code to perform the liftover to the genome positions.

Comment: Excellent advice ! It's now done !